# Using FGallery photo viewer library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to use below library in my application for Photo Viewer. I heard that Apple restricts usage of any third party libraries and application can be rejected from uploading to App store

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

Can anyone give some inputs on this?

Comment: @skram yes, I know that as well... Unfortunately I am not getting correct solutions for my questions after explaining all the details... I am always keeping track of that score and always want to appreciate good answers...

Comment: Mark my answer as the correct one if this satisfies you this time, as it's really the only answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite true, you can use any framework or library you want. As long as it's not using undocumented methods and abides by the Apple guidelines. FGallery is safe to use.